# Worklight SAP Netweaver GateWay Adapter - Client ID

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

Currently we are using the Worklight SAP Netweaver GateWay Adapter to connect to our development environment of SAP. Our customer has configured two client environments 101 and 211. The default is 101.

When creating a connection based on the following adapter configuration...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wl:adapter xmlns:wl="http://www.worklight.com/integration" xmlns:nwgateway="http://www.worklight.com/integration/nwgateway" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="SAPAdapter1">
    <displayName>SAPAdapter1</displayName>
    <description></description>
    <connectivity>
        <connectionPolicy xsi:type="nwgateway:NWGatewayHTTPConnectionPolicyType">
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <domain>10.9.5.27</domain>
            <port>8000</port>
            <serviceRootUrl>/sap/opu/odata/sap/services_x_y_z/</serviceRootUrl>
            <authentication>
                <basic/>
                <serverIdentity>
                    <client>211</client>
                    <username>xyz</username>
                    <password>123</password>
                </serverIdentity>
            </authentication>
        </connectionPolicy>
        <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="10"/>
    </connectivity>
    <procedure name="getShipments"/>
</wl:adapter>
```

We assume to connect to client 211, but apparently we are connected to 101.

How is the client-id handled by the Worklight SAP NWG Adapter?

Comment: As mentioned by Chris, this may be a defect in the product - please open a PMR in order to follow up on this.

Answer (score 0):

This has been identified as a defect in the product.
There is no available workaround.

To receive an iFix containing the fix for this defect, you need to open a PMR (support ticket).
Please mention this question as well as APAR #PI31148 in your query for reference.